# How do I handle multiple inputs in GDB without rerunning the target process?

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm debugging a program which takes a lot of inputs during its course of execution, so it's basically like this:

1. ask for user input
2. do some stuff
3. ask another input
4. do more stuff

Now, I know how to handle this when the program asks just one input, ie **"r < inputfile1"** , but how can I do this systematically to pass multiple input files while debugging the target? Because if I try to do **"r < inputfile1"** and then **"r < inputfile2"** it'll restart the execution altogether. How do I go about this?

Comment: sounds like you want to concatenate the files together?  `cat inputfile1 inputfile2 | r`

Comment: "ask for user input" for what it's worth, prompting for user input is really common in entry level programming classes, but virtually nonexistent in real life computing.   Data usually goes through stdin, not parameters.